# How to graph a curve finding the Cartesian equation

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, curves

I have to graph the curve
$$\gamma(t)=\left(\frac{t^3}3-t,(\ln t)^2\right)$$
with $t>0$. How can I express the curve as a function graph? Maybe I have to put $\frac{t^3}3=x$? I don't think this is the best way, but I only know this method. Can you help me?

If you want to know, the curve is simple and it is regular $\forall t\ne1$.

Comment: what base has the logarithm function?

Comment: It is the natural logarithm

Comment: you can solve $$y=(\ln(t))^2$$ for $t>0$

Comment: Why do you want a parametric curve to be necessarily the graph of a function? A circle is *not* !

Comment: @Bernard how would you graph this curve?

Comment: You have to study the variations of  $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ separately, find the critical points for each of them,   study the nature of singular points (points which are critical for both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$). Here the value $t=1$ yields a singular point. Finally you have to determine whether the curve has oblique asymptotes (when $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ both tend to $\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to describe the curve by some expression $y=f(x)$, as we will see, but that's not really necessary. In gnuplot, you'd do something like

```
gnuplot> set parametric

dummy variable is t for curves, u/v for surfaces
gnuplot> plot [t=0.1:2] t**3/3-t, (log(t))**2
```

and get a decent graph:
[image: parametric plot]
As you can see, the point corresponding to $t=1$, i.e. $(x,y)=(-2/3, 0)$, is *not* a regular one.